# JavaFX set item value twice on ListView with only one item will deselect the item (bug?)

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am writing JavaFX applications with e(fx)clipse. I think that I have encountered a UI bug but I am not sure if it is by design.

So I have two pieces of code, each of them has a `ListView<String>` set as the scene of the primary stage. The first `ListView` contains only one item whereas the other `ListView` contains multiple items. When I have a list item selected on both `ListView` and I **edit the list item twice programmatically**, the `ListView` with only one item will have the selected item deselected while the selected item on the `ListView` with multiple items will remain selected.

Surprisingly if the list item on the `ListView` with only one item is edited once instead of twice, it will remain selected. So it seems that the problem only happens since the second edit.

Here is the complete code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<String> lv = new ListView<String>();
        lv.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")));
        //remove B and C for the ListView with only one item
        stage.setScene(new Scene(lv, 200, 200));
        stage.show();
        lv.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        lv.getItems().set(0, "B");
        lv.getItems().set(0, "C");
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see one ListView. Where is the other one?

Comment: @Steven Please edit the code and remove B and C from the ``asList()`` method for the second ``ListView``.